# I am using SVG style to apply the css property to an element. The code snippet is below:

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am using SVG style to apply the css property to an element. The code snippet is below:

```
        var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
            .data(dataset)                
            .enter()                
            .append("g")
            .style("fill", function(d, i) {
                return colors(i) ; // colors object has some data already                
        }
```

However, this is an attribute style and will be overrode by some external css file. I can not change that external css. Is there a way to make this "SVG.style" to be an inline style? So it won't be overrode.

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: That is an inline style. A (CSS mapped) attribute style would use .attr rather than .style

Answer (score 0):

The way you override CSS normally would be to use the `style` attribute.

```
<rect style="fill: red;" ... />
```

See the following demo:

```js
d3.selectAll("rect").style("fill", "green");
```

```css
rect {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <rect width="100" height="100"/>
</svg>
```

But that's what you are doing, so something else must be going on.

You are applying the style to the `<g>` element, so probably the CSS is overriding that because it has a more specific.  In other words, it probably targets the child directly rather than the parent group.

Your solution would be to get more specific as well. Target the elements you want to change, rather than their parent group.

```js
d3.selectAll("g *").style("fill", "green");
```

```css
rect {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <g>
    <rect width="100" height="100"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```